# Branching a iterator without deep copying its elements

Tags: rust, iterator, move-semantics

Iterators is consumed by `map`, so require `cloned`(equals to `clone`?) when mapping a iterator multiple times. I have following code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a: Vec<(&str, (&i32, &i32))> = vec![("0", (&0, &1)), ("1", (&2, &3))];
    let iter = a.iter().map(|x| x.1 as (&i32, &i32));

    // occur clone process on i32?
    let xs: Vec<&i32> = iter.cloned().map(|(x, _)| x).collect();
    
    let ys: Vec<&i32> = iter.map(|(_, y)| y).collect();
    println!("{:?}", xs);
    println!("{:?}", ys);
}
```

The problem is that `cloned` method probably deep copy whole an iterated element even though the elements contain immutable references. Cloned elements is i32 in above, but it may actually have big structure. I want to explicitly shallow copy elements which contain references to i32 (actually bigger struct) when branch iterator `iter`. Is it possible?

Comment: `cloned` clones the elemtens from the iterator, not the iterator itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `clone` instead of `cloned`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a: Vec<(&str, (&i32, &i32))> = vec![("0", (&0, &1)), ("1", (&2, &3))];
    let iter = a.iter().map(|x| x.1 as (&i32, &i32));

    // occur clone process on i32?
    let xs: Vec<&i32> = iter.clone().map(|(x, _)| x).collect();
    
    let ys: Vec<&i32> = iter.map(|(_, y)| y).collect();
    println!("{:?}", xs);
    println!("{:?}", ys);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fe0196222dcdf3b93b4ac0462e24e60e)

`clone` clones the iterator itself. Meanwhile `cloned` clones the underlying elements, from the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Cloned.html):

> Cloned: An iterator that clones the elements of an underlying iterator.

Comment: Thanks! I misunderstanded `cloned` and `clone` is what I need. But I still wonder a bit why iterator in example is not implemented `Copy` trait and not automatically copied. Do you have easy explanation?

Comment: @winjii notice that copy types are copied automatically when needed but clone is explicit. Makes sense that iterators are cloned explicitly when you need, so you do not end up with a copy mess :)

Comment: It seemed like meaning clone expensive that `Clone` trait is implemented and `Copy` is not. But surely, cloning explicitly may have no mistake and mess than implicitly. I'll use `clone` because problems don't exist at least 